# how to customize tooltip in Chart Js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, linechart

I want to customize the label of the tooltip on chart js. I just want to show as bold the value of portfolio (+2,5%).

```
I found this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nosensus/hhcyhjf9/
```

When i apply it, my tooltip is always on the left bottom, not on the chart.
How can fix it? I am using Chart.js 2.9.4 version and developing with Angular.

[tooltip of the chart should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoMVv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put the text you would like to be bold between these tags:
`<strong>...</strong>`

Like below :

```js
tooltip: {
  trigger: 'item',
  formatter: '<strong>{a}</strong> <br/> {b}:{c}'
},
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL4B4.png)